# Tableview to itself and to Viewcontroller [Multiple segues]

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, ios6, uistoryboardsegue

I have a `UITableView` with many cells and depends on the cell's content it suppused to go to the same `UITableView` with new cells or to a `UIViewController`. I can do this but not at the same time, is it possible to do it?

I thought in a prepareForSegue method like this one:

```
 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
 {
      NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

     if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"NextLevel"]) {
         [segue.destinationViewController setActualNodo:[actualNodo getSonAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
     } else if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Service"]) {
         [segue.destinationViewController setServiceName: whatever]
     }

 }
```

The problem is in the Storyboard that I can't ctrl+drag two segues from the same cell. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible for segues in IB. You can check for different segues that all originate from your controller the way you show in prepareForSegue, but a UI element can only have one segue connected to it.

To do what you want, you should make a segue from the table view controller itself to the new controller. Then, in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, use whatever logic you want to decide whether to go to this new controller (with `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:]`), or to update the table view with new cells.

Comment: I finally got it. Thanks for all. Now my problem is that if a do a [self.tableview reloadData] I can't 'go back' in my nav and I need it but I think that it could be better if I open other question.